# Passing a variable from Access2010 to stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access-2010

I have created an SSIS package that runs from the following stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery ASVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @ServerName VARCHAR(200)
SET @ServerName ='myServerName'
SET @SQLQuery ='DTExec /F ^"\\...\...\My_Package.dtsx^" '
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @SQLQuery
```

I then have an Access2010 application with a few buttons that run 3 procedures all set up the same way running the package using the following code:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim sConnString As String

sConnString = "Provider=sqloledb; Server=MyServerName; Database=MyDB; Trusted_Connection=True; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

conn.Open sConnString

With cmd
  .ActiveConnection = conn
  .CommandType = adCmdText
  .CommandText = "EXEC my_sproc;"
```

Now I need to add text boxes to two of the buttons that trigger the procedures where a user will enter a file name. The button needs to pass that file name to the stored procedure and the stored procedure needs to then use it in the package.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. This is my first time doing something like this and I am a little lost.

Thanks,
 Scott

**UPDATE:**
I altered my procedure and it works with the temporary value in the procedure for @FileName. I am not sure now how to get the value from Access into the @FileName variable though.

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @SSISPath VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(1000)
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(1000)

SET @SSISPath = '\\Server\...\...\...\...\Package.dtsx'
SET @FilePath = '\Server\...\...\...\'
SET @FileName = 'myImportFile.txt' --temp value - need to get value from Access form text box

SELECT @cmd = 'dtexec /f "' + @SSISPath + '"'
SELECT @cmd = @cmd + ' /SET \Package.Variables[User::FileName].Properties[Value];"' + @FilePath + @FileName + '"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `@FileName` an input parameter ...

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE my_sproc 
    -- input parameter:
    @FileName VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @SSISPath VARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @FilePath VARCHAR(1000)        

    SET @SSISPath = '\\Server\...\...\...\...\Package.dtsx'
    -- and so on
```

... and then call the stored procedure with a parameter, along the lines of the following

```vbs
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .CommandText = "my_sproc"
    .Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@FileName", adVarChar, adParamInput, 1000, Me.SomeTextBox.Value)
    .Execute
End With
```